# Styling Cordova in-app-browser

Tags: css, html, cordova

Is there a way to style the Cordova plugin that opens a browser window inside the app? ([In app browser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser))

The bar at the bottom is what needs to be styled to fit the style of the rest of the app.

[image: In app browser window]

Answer (score 1):

So far I know, from html/css/javascript "NO",
from native code "Yes"

You can directly change the plugin's native code.

Like in android, inside InAppBrowsser.java, this line

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.LTGRAY);
```

Don't know which line to change in iOS. Remember to change the java file inside the platform folder too along with the outer plugin folder's java file.

Answer (score 1):

I've forked InAppBrowser and created plugin that allows you to style the browser extensively. But I've only done it for iOS and Android. Please take a look
https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for an answer to this. 
I was able to change the color of the toolbar.

In your `CDVInAppBrowser.m` file, you can edit following line:

```
self.closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:241.0 / 255.0 green:136.0 / 255.0 blue:0.0 / 250.0 alpha:1];
```

And add following lines:

```
self.backButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.forwardButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Resulting in this
[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDRLM.png)

Comment: Is there a way to disallow the main window from being overflowed by the toolbar?  My inAppBrowser toolbar cuts off the top of the HTML page it is including. My toolbar is at the top but I want to have it push the main window down instead of float over it.  Any way to do they in the CDVInAppBrowser.m file?

Comment: @Skippy, unfortunately I have no idea. I didn't have that problem but if I find a solution to it i'll post it here!

Comment: Only way I found was to inject the CSS and add a margin-top to the body